# Strategies/techniques for crash reporting in Java

Tags: java, error-handling, crash

I'm developing a new Java desktop application and would like to include a crash reporting facility - you know the kind of thing - program crashes, box pops up asking user to click okay to send it, etc.

I'm comfortable with how the error will be sent back to our servers - probably via a simple web service.  What I'm more unsure about is how the mechanism for capturing the failure should be implemented?.  I would welcome any advice from anyone that has implemented something similar.

Comment: Also discovered a nice way to track JVMs:  using a thing called Java-Monitor.com .  Its not free but the code is exposed enough that you might be able implement something like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three cases:

1. Catastrophes. The JVM itself is either dead or dying. You cannot assume that any of your code will be able to work - for example you can't allocate any memory. Hence in this case you can't reasonably hope to be able to send any diagnostics. The best you can hope for is to have some diagnostics such as core dumps left in the ashes of the dead program.
   In this case you could on startup of a new run look for such debris and suggest that the user gather it or, rather more effort attempt to assemble a diagnostic package yourself.
2. The low-level application code does not catch an exception, perhaps a RunTime exception such as a NullPointer exception. In this case you could in your main (assuming you have one) you could catch Exception and have some hope your that your Crash Reporter code will work.
   Pass the exception, and it's stack trace, to the Crash Reporter.
3. You low level code catches something really unhealthy. Not enough to terminate process, but worth reporting. Here you not only have the exception to hand but other contextual information. We have rather more to send to the Crash Reporter.

Comment: A desktop application effectively has no main method. The main thread ends when the frame is shown (and whatever else it does until the method finishes).

Comment: In most cases yes, that's why I said "if you have one", but there are some non-ui desktop apps that can have a main. Anyway it would be good to know what you would recommend in the case when have no main.

Answer (score 7):

There is a command line option you can give the JVM that will run a batch file after the JVM crashes with a memory dump.   All you do is create a external program that does the error reporting and then use the JVM option to send the core dump in email using the utility you made.

```
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnError="<cmd args>;<cmd args>"
```

Comment: of course, you would want to combine this method with a runtime error reporting capability also...

Answer (score 5):

Use Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler and the static Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler to (attempt to) report exceptions to your logging system.

Answer (score 2):

Use logging. The generic pattern works like this:

- Create an appender that sends the error message to the server (most logging frameworks support appenders that transmit log messages via mail or even JDBC). If there is no existing appender, they have examples how to do that.
- Add that appender to the root logger and set it's threshold to `ERROR`
- Log an error when you notice an exception. The logging framework will then do the plumbing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best that Java currently has to offer, but this is what I did a while back.

First all interesting activity likely to crash was dispatched via a command pattern. This application consisted of hitting an application server over the internet, so a lot could go wrong. The exceptions were caught by the command dispatcher and the appropriate result displayed to the user (generally showing an error dialog followed by a shutdown and an e-mail sent about the crash).

Second, a custom event queue was used in Swing to catch any exceptions that happen on the event thread. I would hope that Java has a better solution by now, but basically when an exception happened you had to check if your code was involved, otherwise some Swing bugs could crash your application, which isn't pleasant. And of course recursion had to be checked for (the crash repeating itself over and over again as you try to display a message to the user).

By the way, most any crash will keep your JVM going, including out of memory errors, enough to send an e-mail in most cases, as after an out of memory error generally the error releases enough of the stack (and therefore heap) to allow for further garbage collection and letting your code live. But in such an event you should still exit quickly. IDEA keeps going after an out of memory error, but often isn't functioning well. They would be better off exiting, IMO.

You push a new Queue with the following and subclass EventQueue to link in your behavior.

```
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().push(newQueue);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use BugSense. It is targeted towards mobile-application crash reporting but the API states that it could be used for any kind of crash reporting. It's quite simple from what I've read and all one needs to do is create a simple POST request with all the values.

```
{
   "client": {
      "name": "bugsense-android", // Obligatory
      "version": "0.6"
   },
   "request": {
      "remote_ip": "10.0.0.1",
      "custom_data": {
         "key1": "value1",
         "key2": "value2"
      }
   },
   "exception": {
      "message": "java.lang.RuntimeException: exception requested", // Obligatory
      "where": "MainActivity.java:47", // Obligatory
      "klass": "java.lang.RuntimeException", // Type of exception
      "backtrace": "java.lang.RuntimeException: exception requested\r\nat com.sfalma.trace.example.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)\r\nat android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)\r\nat android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)\r\nat android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)\r\nat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)\r\nat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)\r\nat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)\r\nat java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)\r\nat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)\r\nat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)\r\nat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)\r\nat dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)\\n" // Obligatory
   },
   "application_environment": {
      "phone": "android", // Device model (could be PC or Max) Obligatory
      "appver": "1.2", // Obligatory
      "appname": "com.sfalma", // Obligatory
      "osver": "2.3", // Obligatory
      "wifi_on": "true",
      "mobile_net_on": "true",
      "gps_on": "true",
      "screen_dpi(x:y)": "120.0:120.0",
      "screen:width": "240",
      "screen:height": "400",
      "screen:orientation": "normal"
   }
}
```

You can [read more about it here](http://www.bugsense.com/docs/api).