# Collect exception reports in Java application

Tags: java, exception, error-reporting

I'm currently maintaining a Desktop Java application that has a small to medium user base. I often get some pretty useless mails saying that "something went wrong" and I'm left digging through the source code, often unable to reproduce the problem.

Now I'm wondering if there is a library that would allow me to collect Exceptions when they happen, present a small dialog to the users and if/when they agree, post the stack trace to my webserver. Basically what I'm looking for is something similar to [Application Crash Report for Android (ACRA)](http://acra.ch/), but for desktop Java applications.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312851/strategies-techniques-for-crash-reporting-in-java

Comment: You could put it in a log file by calling `System.setErr(new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.File(filename)));` at the start of your application. This will output everything from `System.err` to the file.

Comment: I would use logging, use SLF4j or log4j to store the error in a defined log file. But thats just me http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html

Comment: @cdecker Can you give us an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of the code showing how these emails get sent to you? For example, do you use some sort of logging framework where the logger sends the email?

Comment: We already are logging using SLF4J, but I don't yet have a way to automatically deliver the logs and the stacktrace details back to our servers, where we want to collect, prioritize and fix the causes. What I need is some library that can be called from inside an exception handler to collect information about the Application (version, configuration, ...) and the exception that is being handled, and then delivers it to our servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SLF4J and Logback, you can configure an appender to send detailed error reports to a [Ctrlflow Automated Error Reporting](https://ctrlflow.com/automated-error-reporting/) server (which offers filtering and aggregation of incoming reports + dashboards + email digest). This [blog post](https://blog.ctrlflow.com/automated-error-reporting-logback-setup/) has all the information on how to configure Logback accordingly.

If you want to present your user with a confirmation dialog first, you may have to extend the existing appender, though – unless your “Desktop Java application” is an “Eclipse Rich Client Platform applications.” In that case the work has already been done for you. See this [webinar](https://blog.ctrlflow.com/webinar-setting-automated-error-reporting-eclipse-ide-plug-rcp-application/) for more information.